# Ruby. Selenium. Proxy. Proxy not work

Tags: ruby, selenium, proxy

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'selenium-webdriver'

@p = File.read("proxy.txt")
@proxies = @p.split(/::/)
@proxy =  @proxies[rand(@proxies.count)]

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(proxy: Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(http: @proxy))
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.get("http://showip.net/")
```

This code is working, mean open windows blah blah, but every time I see my own local IP address not PROXY. It means proxy not work.
I very need working with proxy prototype.
Would you help me? Pleaseee...

Thank you.

Comment: Tip: `@proxies.sample` for a random entry from an array.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're declaring it with the correct options:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

And then for reasons unexplained you go and declare it *again*, stomping the previous one, with one that has no options:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
```

The second instance shouldn't be there. Delete it.

Comment: Yes I delete second string. But problem still here, proxy not work. Page shows my own address. Not a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

your declaring a capability for firefox but then setting up a proxy for chrome

Answer (score -1):

This is the method I use to successfully create a browser proxy instance in Selenium Webdriver. You may edit it to read the file for the proxy, just amend the `PROXY = "10.0.0.0:8080"`

```
begin
  PROXY = "10.0.0.0:8080"

  proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(
      :http     => PROXY,
  )

  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(:proxy => proxy)

  $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps
end
```